# inconsistencies between admob stats and firebase stats

Tags: android, firebase, admob, firebase-analytics

We have been using fire base and admob for a few months. The accounts are linked but fire base is reporting very different stats for impressions and click compared to admob. Firebase is reporting ~800 impressions where admob is reporting ~8,000 for the same period. It's very odd because all the other events seem to be consistent. Any ideas why this might be?

Mike

Comment: There are some known reasons why FB and AdMob can disagree, which are listed at https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7378163?hl=en#dataconsistency. I'd recommend contacting the troubleshooting team, and seeing if they can tell you anything specific to your apps and setup: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting.